# VSCode Go extention not loading: panic occurred in the loadImport function of the cmd/go/internal/load package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded the Golang source code via [Github](https://github.com/golang/go). I'm trying to open it in VSCode with the Go extention installed. When I open the project directory, I get the error below. How do I resolve this?

> Error loading workspace: packages.Load error: err: exit status 2:
> stderr: panic: LoadImport called with empty package path [recovered]
> panic: LoadImport called with empty package path goroutine 1
> [running]: cmd/go/internal/load.(*preload).flush(0x140002f89a0)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.20.2/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go:1093
> +0x80 panic({0x100ec5160, 0x100f71e08}) /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.20.2/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x1f4
> cmd/go/internal/load.loadImport({0x100f79258, 0x140000280f8}, {0x0,
> 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1}, 0x0, {0x14000f7a68e, ...}, ...)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.20.2/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go:697
> +0xe6c cmd/go/internal/load.LoadImport(...) /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.20.2/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go:689
> cmd/go/internal/load.(*Package).load(0x140017cc580, {0x100f79258,
> 0x140000280f8}, {0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1}, {0x140004172a4, ...},
> ...)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.20.2/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go:1970
> +0x16a8 c...